# How can I get a specific value from a JSON URL, and pass it into a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables, url

I want to use a JSON URL to get up-to-date exchange rates for use in a webpage. For this I want to be able to get a specific exchange rate (say, US Dollar) and pass the rate onto a variable so I can use it in a JS function.

Here is a sample of the JSON code:

```
"rates": {
    "AED": 3.672796,
    "AFN": 57.951451,
    "ALL": 112.589601,
    "AMD": 430.416,
    "ANG": 1.787,
    "AOA": 100.82775,
    "ARS": 8.52454,
    "AUD": 1.175504,
    "AWG": 1.79,
    "AZN": 0.784233,
    "BAM": 1.571689,
    "BBD": 2
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the JSON code to a variable, e.g.`var json = "{your json string}"` then parse it with `var obj = JSON.parse( json );`. Now you can access the elements from `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify to turn a JavaScript variable into a JSON string and JSON.parse to do the opposite. Then you can access properties directly (obj.SomeProperty) or dynamically (obj["SomeProperty"].